# Create an Option of type function so the function can be executed later?

Tags: scala

I don't know how to articulate my question other than by providing an example of what I would like to do and explain why it doesn't work.

I would like to do something like the following:

```
def yes() { println("yes") }
def no() { println("no") }
def blank() {}

var handler: Option[() => Unit] = Some(blank)
...
handler = Some(yes)
...
handler.foreach(f => f())
```

This does not work because the defined functions are of type Unit, not () => Unit. So Some(blank) can not be assigned as type Option[()=>Unit].

Next I tried:

```
var handler: Option[Unit] = Some(blank)
...
handler = Some(yes)
...
handler.foreach(f => f())
```

This allows me to assign the functions to the handler, but then I can't invoke the function within Option's foreach function.

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Follow the style guide. `def yes() { println("yes") }` should be `def yes(): Unit = println("yes")` and you don't need a "blank" just use `() => Unit`.  Finally use underscore notation when possible `handler.foreach(_())`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> This does not work because the defined functions are of type Unit, not
>   () => Unit. So Some(blank) can not be assigned as type
>   Option[()=>Unit].

Actually it works as expected.

Type of expression `yes()` is `Unit`, but the type of expression `yes` depends on context.

In context of `() => Unit` compiler could convert `yes` to something like `() => yes()`.

You could create function `() => Unit` from method `yes` manually like this:

```
val functionYes = yes _

handler = Some(functionYes)
```

But compiler is smart enough to convert method to function in context where function is expected, like `Some(yes)`.

Take a look at this example:

```
1 to 10 foreach println
```

`println` here is the method `Predef.println`, so compiler have to convert it to function.

Comment: Lesson learned! Next time I won't post on SO unless I validate the problem truly exists. In this case, I thought it was a problem because IntelliJ syntax highlighting reported this as an error.

Comment: @axiopisty: IDEA is good, but not perfect. To make it happy you could specify type manually: `Some[() => Unit](yes)`.

Comment: I don't think you can say yes has no type.  Otherwise, they couldn't call their company TypeSafe. Also, converting method to func is not "compiler smarts" in the sense of implementation detail, but is required by spec. But in presence of type inference (because we didn't say `Some[()=>Unit](yes)`) maybe there's an interesting edge case.

Comment: @som-snytt, you are correct. `has no type` fixed to `type depends on context`. About `compiler smarts`: it's just a simplification.

Answer (score 2):

It's worth supplying some vocabulary here.

The type of a method

```
def foo(): Unit = ???
```

is `()Unit` (3.3.1 method types in the spec).

If you leave off the parens,

```
def foo: Unit = ???
```

then the type is `=> Unit`.

That chapter of the spec calls them "non-value types" because you can't use them as a value.

If you want a value of type `() => Unit`, it applies a conversion.  See 6.26.5 of the spec, where it is called "eta expansion."

I bet you saw the failure by leaving off the parens at some point:

```
scala> def foo: Unit = ???
foo: Unit

scala> var handler: Option[() => Unit] = Some(foo)
<console>:8: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: () => Unit
       var handler: Option[() => Unit] = Some(foo)
                                              ^
```

In this case, the conversion you're getting is "evaluation" (6.26.2).

This is a case where it matters if you supplied parens in the method definition.

Since "procedure syntax" is deprecated, maybe it's useful to practice not using it.

Comment: Useful information about `non-value types`, I didn't know this term. Funny thing is that `foo _` still creates a `() => Unit`. For me it looks like inconsistence between `foo _` and `foo: (() => Unit)`.

Comment: @senia if I understand you, `=> Unit` is special-cased in 6.7 Method Values, so `foo _` is `() => Unit`, whether foo is paramless def or call-by-name param as in `def f(g: =>Unit) = g _`.